# To print FileName and selected rows:

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to print first 2 rows from all the files located in the directory along with File Name.
All are .csv extension files. Having around 100 files in that directory.

sample_jan.csv

```
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
50,Jan,500
```

sample_feb.csv

```
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
40,Feb,800
60,Feb,1200
```

Expected Output:

```
Filename:sample_jan.csv
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300

Filename:sample_feb.csv
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
```

Tried to list 2 rows for individual files  like below but don't know how to loop for all the files.

```
cat sample_jan.csv | head -2 >>output.csv
cat sample_feb.csv | head -2 >>output.csv

cat *.csv | head -2 >output.csv
```

Looking for your suggestions, dont have perl & python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print "Filename:" FILENAME}FNR<3' *.csv
Filename:sample_jan.csv
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
Filename:sample_feb.csv
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
```

**or**

If you have GNU awk and your files are very big then this could be an option:

```
$ gawk 'FNR==1{print "Filename:" FILENAME}FNR>2{nextfile}1' *.csv
Filename:sample_jan.csv
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
Filename:sample_feb.csv
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
```

Comment: Jaypal, FileName is not printing if the source input is *.gz (gunzip) files , for example when i tried , zcat sample_jan.csv.gz | awk 'FNR==1{print "Filename:" FILENAME} FNR<3' > Output.txt

Comment: got this output: Filename:-
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300 where Filename appears is blank

Comment: @AVN `FILENAME` variable does not get populated when you read from pipe.

Comment: Jaypal, please suggest how to capture filename for Gunzip source files

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
awk '
  FNR == 1  {if(NR!=1)print""; printf("Filename:%s\n", FILENAME)}
  FNR < 3
' *.csv
```

**Explanation**

Recall that:

- records default to lines
- NR counts records starting at 1 and doesn't reset between files
- FNR counts records starting at 1 and resets to 1 each file.

Script:

```
FNR == 1 {  # If it's the first record of the current file then:
    if (NR != 1) # If it's NOT the first record of all files
        print "";  #   then print an empty line
    printf("Filename:%s\n", FILENAME) # Print the filename
}

# If record number of current file is < 3 then
# perform default action (print the record).
FNR < 3
```

If you have too many files to fit on the command line (after the expansion of `*.csv`), then you could try this:

```
find -name '*.csv' -execdir awk '
  FNR == 1 {
    file = FILENAME
    sub(/^\.\//, "", file)
    printf("\nFilename:%s\n", file)
  }
  FNR < 3
' '{}' +
```

The find command above will execute awk with as large a list of filenames as will fit on the command line (`'{}' +` is replaced with this list), running awk as many times as necessary, but the minimum number of times.

The substitution in the awk script strips the `./` from the front of the filenames before they are printed.

Comment: You might want to add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
For file in *
do
    echo "Filename:$file" >> output.csv
    head -2 $file >> output.csv
    echo
done
```

There's no need to `cat` and pipe the files into head.  It can take the filename as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop ocer all `.csv` files in the directory like that:

`for f in *.csv; do YOUR_COMMAND; done`

That should be combinable with your commands:

`for f in *.csv; do cat "$f" | head -2 >>output.csv ; done`

(Untested - just for the idea)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care the label `Filename:` you can just:

```
head -n2 * > output.csv
```